# Angularjs without controller

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, version

Today I saw a [tweet](https://twitter.com/pkozlowski_os/status/525193352015519744) from Pawel Kozlowski that controllers will go away in Angularjs 2.0

Is there anyone know how would angularjs be without controllers? Currently I handle almost everything in controller, and I dont know when the next version released how much our code will change.

Comment: @Josep what is funny?

Comment: "I handle almost everything in controller" >> this is often considered as a bad practice. Angular best practice is to put your logic in the services.

Comment: @PascalLeMerrer yeah you are right, but I think controllers make angular easier.

Comment: whenever that will arrive, you will surely find article on how to map controllers to whatever the new replacement of that will be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.You're right.

**What will not be in AngularJs 2.0?**

1. Controllers
2. Directive Definition Object (DDO)
3. $scope
4. angular.module
5. JqLite

[image]

**Angular 2.0 Core  slides** from ng-europe talk:  [Angular 2.0 Core](https://plus.google.com/108190973756926786179/posts/hymKGAbCVrB)

**About Your question :** Why do you need to go with AJS 2? If your app is giving what you need with AJS 1.X then why do you need to change it to AJS 2.B'cos AJS 1.X series will continue as it is in future also. So no need to worry about it. But if you'll start a new app then you can start it with AJS 2 (if it'll available at that time). That is my suggestion to you.

[**What Google says about the AJS 1.X :**](http://angularjs.blogspot.de/2014/10/ng-europe-angular-13-and-beyond.html)

> If you are building web applications today, this is the version you
>   should use. This is the tried and true version that we really believe
>   in. With over 1600 apps at Google built with Angular 1.x, we are
>   committed to supporting it as the first class AngularJS version for a
>   long time to come.

Comment: Thanks Sampath specially for the link. My apps are currently working like a charm :) but always I like to upgrade my apps if I find the time for that :)